# Read maven server attributes as properties

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a server defined in `.m2/settings.xml` like this:

```
<server>
    <id>foo</id>
    <username>bar</username>
    <password>baz</password>
</server>
```

Is it possible to access those values as properties by using something like `${servers.foo.username}`?

Comment: It is possible like *${settings.servres.foo.username}* but i wouldn't recommend it. The question is why do you need it? May be you can elaborate that a little bit more to get a better impression about what you like to achieve?

Comment: `${settings.servers.foo.username}` doesn't seem to work. I'm using jboss-as-maven-plugin to add a datasource to a running JBoss. I want to take username and password from `<server>`

Comment: What if password is encrypted? See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov, thanks, but not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them by using

- ${settings.servers[0].username}
- ${settings.servers[0].password}
- ${settings.servers[0].id}

which means in result you are bound to a defined order which you can't guarantee. 
In case of testing etc. i would recommend using properties etc. instead of settings.xml parts. The supplemental information you gave sounds like an integration test. Apart from already mentioned problems like encrypted passwords etc.

Comment: `${settings.servers[0].username}` doesn't seem to work either. Could you point me to your source of documentation?

Comment: If this does not works you have other problems (usual behaviour of plugin parameters and injected parameters). Have you tried to print out the information which you are using? Furthermore the question is what does: **doesn't seem to work** exactly mean? Error message ?

Comment: **"doesn't seem to work"** means that if I use `${settings.servers[0].username}` anywhere in the pom I just get *${settings.servers[0].username}*, not *bar*.